# Customize: highlight-symbol-colors added only delta

Tags: customize

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

By default package **highlight-symbol** has 9 colors.
So I add new color, **snow**, to option `highlight-symbol-colors`:

Screenshot:

[image]

OK.

As a result Customize puts this in my init file:

```
(custom-set-variables

 '(highlight-symbol-colors
   (quote
    ("yellow" "DeepPink" "cyan" "MediumPurple1" "SpringGreen1" "DarkOrange" "HotPink1" "RoyalBlue1" "OliveDrab" "snow")))
 )
```

As you can see the variable `highlight-symbol-colors` contains all 10 colors, including `"snow"`.

My question is:

How to make option `highlight-symbol-colors` contain **ONLY** the colors I add, and not also the colors that it has by default?

I want the result to be something like this:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(highlight-symbol-colors
   (quote ("snow"))))
```

So as result I must use **10 colors**.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please edit the title of your question, based on what you think you are really asking. The question is not clear as posed. I corrected the title based on what it seemed you were asking, which was how to use Customize to delete elements from a list value. Your comment to my answer suggests that that is not at all what you want to know.

Comment: IIUC what bothers you is the longish customize snippet. Then you could simply move this to another file. See the variable custom-file.

Answer (score 2):

Of course. In Customize, just click `DEL` for each of the colors that you do not want to include.

`INS` inserts a color value. `DEL` deletes a color value.

---

UPDATE after your comment:

Your comment suggests that you want to use a function in your init file that takes only `"snow"` as argument and adds it to the value of `highlight-symbol-colors`. If not, it is really not clear what you are asking.

If that's what you want, then do it:

```el
(defun foo (&rest colors)
  "Add COLOR to the value of `highlight-symbol-colors`."
  (customize-set-variable 'highlight-symbol-colors
                          (append highlight-symbol-colors colors)))
```

Then put this in your init file: `(foo "snow")`.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry. I want another behavior. I want to be all default colors value (9 colors). But in **init.el** to set only new (**snow**) color. Is it possible? So as result I must use 10 colors.

Comment: That's what I need. I want this because if some another variable has very long default list, I wan't to see ALL items of this list it in **init.el**.

Comment: If the answer is what you need then consider accepting it.